# React app with Firebase flickering on route change

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom, flicker

I am creating a React app that uses Firebase for authentication. Every route change now causes a 1 second delay and a screen flicker. I've traced this back to the `firebase.initializeApp` function being called every page load. Is there any way to mitigate or completely avoid this behavior? My react app is pretty simple and comprised of ChakraUI and react-router-dom but here is my firebase config:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

const clientCredentials = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  // This line gets called every route change
  firebase.initializeApp(clientCredentials);
}

export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is embarrassing but the answer is not necessarily Firebase related. In my component library (ChakraUI), the links are actually rendering as traditional `<a>` tags which triggers a full page refresh in React by default. This makes my problem make sense as firebase would need to be initialized all the time when the app is hard reloading. Converting my internal/ChakraUI link components to properly use `react-router-dom` `<Link>`'s solved the problem by not forcing a full page refresh and firebase stays initialized. Hopefully my silly mistake helps someone in the future!